# Did any Muslim country officially express disagreement over America's plan to have the Palestinian Authority govern over the Gaza Strip?

Tags: israel, palestine, middle-east, gaza, hamas

> "The cooperation between the Palestinian and Israeli [security]
> services is extensive and has withstood any challenge. Every time
> Mahmoud Abbas has wanted to suspend security cooperation, the
> Americans have opposed it and he has fallen in line,” says Jean-Paul
> Chagnollaud, director of the Paris-based Institute for Research and
> Studies on the Mediterranean and Middle East (Institut de recherche et
> d’études Méditerranée Moyen-Orient).
>
> “It's an almost organic relationship, and for many Palestinians,
> security cooperation comes with no political return. That's why many
> accuse the Palestinian Authority of a sort of collaboration."
>
> Chagnollaud says the idea that the PA would return to Gaza – with
> Israeli armoured vehicles – as part of an occupying army would be
> unacceptable to most Palestinians and politically untenable for Abbas
> and his government.

https://www.france24.com/en/middle-east/20231108-can-the-palestinian-authority-lead-a-post-hamas-gaza-strip

Did any Muslim country officially express disagreement over America's plan to have the Palestinian Authority govern over the Gaza Strip, or do some Muslim countries want Hamas or any other group other than the PA or Israel to govern over Gaza after the war? I know some Muslim countries are technically allied with Hamas, but I am wondering if any country has officially expressed disagreement in ousting Hamas in favor of the Palestinian Authority, which is pro-Israel. I am asking this, because it's a solid middle ground and compromise, and I don't see how countries could completely support the actions of Hamas.

Comment: I guess by "technically allied" you mean *de facto*. Hamas has no formal treaties with anyone AFAIK.

Comment: The Palestinian Authority is not "pro-Israel" though it is "anti-Hamas".  On the other hand, Iran is a Muslim country which is "pro-Hamas".

Comment: Could "aim to discredit" close voters explain their reasoning?  Is it the particular citation being used?  (Something more neutral?  But note that the reality or perception of the accusation of collaboration is likely to be a huge dilemma for the PA) Because otherwise it seems a fairly straightforward question.  I suspect Arab countries probably will want to defer making public commitments either way, but wouldn't mind hearing if one does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Who is running the show?**

> Did any Muslim country officially express disagreement over America's plan to have the Palestinian Authority govern over the Gaza Strip?

It is Israelis and Palestinians who are making decisions, neither the Americans, nor Europeans, nor Arab countries, nor Muslim countries. The US certainly works behind the scenes to further its interests, and sometimes is not very subtle about it, but suggesting that it is running the show begs the question of whether the OP is asking in good faith.

**Oslo accords (1993)**
Palestinian Authority is the only legal representative of the Palestinian people, recognized by Israel, and most of the world. In particular, PA represents Palestinians in the United Nations (with an observer status.) PA has been recognized as such in [the Oslo Accords in 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oslo_Accords#Alternatives_to_the_Oslo_Accords), and the *de facto* takeover of Gaza by Hamas in 2007 doesn't change the situation. There have been an on-and-off reconciliation process since then, but the US would hardly breaking a new ground by acknowledging its position since 30 years ago.

**Recognition of Oslo accords**
Oslo accords recognize both Palestinians' and Israelis' national aspirations, as well as the existence of Israel, and pave path to the negotiated two-state solution. Technically, this makes them unacceptable to any country that subscribed to the [Khartoum resolution's *Three Noes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khartoum_Resolution):

> No peace with Israel,
> No negotiation with Israel,
> No recognition of Israel.

Signatories of Khartoum's resolution are Arab states, which are mostly Muslim-majority countries. Since then some of them have accepted Israel. The non-Arab Muslim states are split, with some likewise denying Israel's right to exists (and its *de facto* existence) - notably Iran, whereas others have good relationships with Israel - e.g., [Azerbaijan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijan%E2%80%93Israel_relations).

In addition, the Arab league proposed the [Arab peace initiative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Peace_Initiative), somewhat similar to the Oslo accords, which also holds PA as the representative of the Palestinian people (this initiative is not accepted by Hamas). The Arab relations with Hamas are mostly non-formal political backing and financial and military support.

Comment: This starts well, but seems to stop before answering that Q.  Who currently officially opposes a PA takeover of Gaza in the near future, from all those groups and factions?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica fair criticism. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps the question is really intended as "any Muslim country besides what the PA administers/Palestine" `*`.

But since that isn't specified so far (and since it's also an important consideration), how about the [PA itself](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/oct/29/palestinian-pm-we-will-not-run-gaza-without-solution-for-west-bank) ?   Which is unwilling without at least wo major Israeli concessions:

> But Mohammad Shtayyeh, who has been prime minister since 2019, said the PA would not cooperate without a return to a genuine peace process resulting in two sovereign states.
>
> “To have the Palestinian Authority go to Gaza and run the affairs of Gaza without a political solution for the West Bank, as if this Palestinian Authority is going aboard an F-16 or an Israeli tank?” Shtayyeh said. “I don’t accept it. Our president [Mahmoud Abbas] does not accept it. None of us will accept it.”

`*` Yes, I know, but it's recognized as a country by many UN members, but its independence also really falls short of the autonomy a country *deserves*.

See also [There Might Be No Day After in Gaza - Carnegie Endowment for International Peace](https://carnegieendowment.org/2023/11/03/there-might-be-no-day-after-in-gaza-pub-90920).  Their take, and also The Economist's is that almost no one will want to pull Israel's chestnuts out of the fire and "solve" Gaza for them.

It's not about solid middle ground or compromise, it really boils down to the perception (by the PA, by the UN, by other Arab nations) that, at least without Israel doing some deep concessions after the current operation, Gaza will become a reputational quagmire for whoever runs it *and* possibly a deadly one at that.